# MySQL, how validate against string dates using PHP?

Tags: mysql, string, validation, date

I am working with a table that has existing data in it..

The 'date' column has its data like so:

Saturday, September 26, 2015
Saturday, September 26, 2015
Saturday, September 27, 2015
Saturday, September 27, 2015

etc..etc..

Using PHP (or maybe just straight MySQL?) how can I only pull/list records (data) that are BEFORE a certain date  (todays date)

Something like this.. but with the way the 'date' (cough) is in the3 table. I'm not sure how to handle it properly.

```
SELECT s.sessioncode, s.sessionname, s.sessiontime FROM fc15_sessions AS s  WHERE s.sessiondate < **TODAYS_DATE** ORDER BY s.id
```

Testing with some PHP and messing with that 'date' format...

This seems to work and be something I can work with... but not sure how I put it together in a validation:

```
$string = 'Saturday, September 26, 2015';
$timestamp = strtotime($string);

echo "DATE CHECK: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

MySQL Attempt:

```
SELECT s.id, s.sessiondate, s.sessioncode, s.sessionname, s.sessiontime
FROM fc15_sessions AS s
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(s.sessiondate, '%m/%d/%Y' ) > date( "m/d/Y" )
ORDER BY s.id
```

Comment: You should be storing dates in a `DATE` column in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Human-readable dates have no business being in your database, this is a presentation issue that should be handled in your application. If practical, these should be converted. MySQL will have a very tough time dealing with these in any non-trivial capacity: They can't be indexed, each query requires expensive conversion. If `strtotime` can deal with them, maybe writing a quick script to transpose from that format to the right one would help get you there.

Comment: Thanks.  But the data is what it is.  Its use for outputting on the screen,. instead of a legit 'date'... (in a m/d/Y format)..  either way I need to use this field/data as a validation on what to display or not.

(Update main post with a SQL try)

Comment: You just can't do that. Store dates as `DATE` unless you have an *extremely* compelling reason to not do this. Formatting is a display issue, it costs nothing to render out dates as strings. On the other hand, dealing with formatted dates in the database is cripplingly expensive. That `STR_TO_DATE` function there will be absolutely brutal on non-trival sets of data.

Comment: I am echoing what everyone else said -- store the dates as DATEs in MySQL. If you want the output to a screen in another format, format the date when you display it. If you don't change this, you're going to cause yourself no end of problems later on.

Comment: please re-read.

The data is what it is.  There is no changing it.

* These are NOT answers/comments that are on topic.  

In PHP using stringtotime() (as posted above) works for parse the date correctly.  So there is no way in MySQL to do this?  (Thats abetter answer than saying change the data in the table when mentioned it cant be changed)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this MySQL functions:

> - STR_TO_DATE( *string, format* )
> - DATE_FORMAT( *date, format* )
> - CURDATE() or equivalently CURRENT_DATE()

So your final MySQL query becames:

```
SELECT s.sessioncode, s.sessionname, s.sessiontime  
FROM fc15_sessions AS s  
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(s.sessiondate, '%W, %M %d, %Y'),"%Y-%m-%d") < CURDATE()
ORDER BY s.id
```

> **NOTE:** You must use the format *"%Y%m%d"* or *"%Y-%m-%d"* (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD with or without separator) for correct date string compare. 
> In this case you must use the format **"%Y-%m-%d"** as the function *CURDATE()* (or equivalently *CURRENT_DATE()*) returns the results in this format.

Comment: [Please do not link to w3schools](http://w3fools.com/). It's a resource that's often filled with dangerously out of date advice, especially for PHP. Instead, link to the latest version of the official MySQL documentation when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately.. in the end (and against all the comments it cant be done)..

This is what worked for me in the end.  (Properly using the STR_TO_DATE params, I had it wrong, its how the data currently is formatted, not HOW you want it formatted)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(targetColumn, '%W, %M %d, %Y'),'%m/%d/%Y') FROM tableName;
```

Comment: @P. Sarrapochiello

I see you updated your answer.. (fair enough)..  Accepted.